# c# Event Handlers Subscription Issue

Tags: c#

I have a class A that defines an event like public event EventHandler OnCommandReply;
I have two other classes that subscribe to that event. However when the event is fired is only one of the classes that receive the event. I would like to know how to make both receive the event that is fired.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure both classes subscribe to the event? When you place breakpoints on the respective lines where the subscription happens, are they reached?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: The subscriptions happened

Comment: @BigToch we need some code to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your error, but I couldn't... This is what I tried:

```
public void Main()
{
  var a = new A();

  var b = new B();
  var c = new C();

  a.SomethingChanged += b.OnSomethingChanged;
  a.SomethingChanged += c.OnSomethingChanged;

  a.RaiseSomethingChangedEvent();
}

private class A
{
  public event EventHandler SomethingChanged;

  public void RaiseSomethingChangedEvent()
  {
    if(SomethingChanged !=null)
      SomethingChanged(this, new EventArgs());
  }
}

private class B
{
  public void OnSomethingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("B: Event was raised.");
  }
}

private class C
{
  public void OnSomethingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("C: Event was raised.");
  }
}
```

Comment: What I did is that I subscribe to the events using two instance of the class A.

Comment: Okay, but then both instances of class A need to raise an event in order to notify all listeners or declare the event as static

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe the event correctly, always both should be fired. Are you sure you du not unsubscribe the event with `-=`? Or set it to null?

Do you correctly subscribe your event with `+=`?

Subscribing

```
publisher.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
```

Unsubscribing:

```
 publisher.RaiseCustomEvent -= HandleCustomEvent;
```

Here is a good article about that: [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you don't use the = operator when registering an event subscriber with a publisher. Doing so would replace any/all currently registered event subscribers with the current subscriber. Instead, be sure to use the += operator to cause the current subscriber to be appended to the event handler's invocation list.